# How to make my cpp code smaller and look more sustainable?

Tags: c++

Hello guys currently I am kinda between entry and medium level on C++. I made 2 class which they include carModel,carBrand,carAge and carPrice. I defined both A and B classes. I also used void function to design a basic menu. I got the data option as using switch case. Here is my question how can I make them smaller I mean less code lines.

If anybody can't see my codes here the code lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>
#include <ctype.h>
using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

void carMenu() {

    cout << " ---    WELCOME TO CAR MENU --- " << endl;
    cout << "---   Choose car model A or Choose car model B  --- " << endl;
    
};

class A {
public:
    string carModelA;
    string carBrandA;
    double carPriceA;
    int carAgeA;


};

class B {
public:
    string carModelB;
    string carBrandB;
    double carPriceB;
    int carAgeB;

};

int main() 
{
    carMenu();
    char option;
    cout << "Please Enter an option " << endl;
    cin >> option;
    A carA;
    B carB;
    carA.carModelA = "Sedan";
    carA.carBrandA = "Ford";
    carA.carPriceA = 25500;
    carA.carAgeA = 5;

    carB.carModelB = "Hatchback";
    carB.carBrandB = "Toyota";
    carB.carPriceB = 15500;
    carB.carAgeB = 2;

    switch (option) {
    case 'A':
        cout << "Car model A is " << carA.carModelA << endl;
        cout << "Car Brand A is " << carA.carBrandA << endl;
        cout << "Car model A is " << carA.carPriceA << endl;
        cout << "Car model A is " << carA.carAgeA << endl;
        break;
    case'B':
        cout << "Car model B is " << carB.carModelB << endl;
        cout << "Car Brand B is " << carB.carBrandB << endl;
        cout << "Car model B is " << carB.carPriceB << endl;
        cout << "Car model B is " << carB.carAgeB << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "You did not choose a option :" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You could put it all on *one* line if you really wanted to. It would be illegible, but it would be literally minimal line count. My point is, less lines does not mean better code; it means less lines. period. Changing the *design* and *architecture* of your code, on the other hand, could *potentially* reduce code footprint *and* improve robustness. That said, there is no possible "right" answer to this question. It is open to *wide* speculation, interpretation, and opinion, and as such as not a good fit for this forum. codereview.stackexchange.com or similar may be a better option.

Comment: You can remove one class since looks the same, printing to stdout may be enclosed in the operator<< overload, two instances of car may be stored in one array instead of two variables. There is many possibilities

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, `A` and `B` are structurally the same, so you may as well have just one of them, and have multiple instances of that single class. As you only have public data, you can use the keyword `struct`, which declares a class with public as the default access.

Similarly, rather than having two variables, `carA` and `carB`, you could have a collection of `Car` instances.

Similarly you can write a function that displays a `Car`, rather than repeating the `cout << "Car attribute id is " << data << endl`.

```
struct Car {
    std::string model;
    std::string brand;
    double price;
    int age;
};

void printMenu() {
    std::cout << " ---    WELCOME TO CAR MENU --- " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---   Choose car model A or Choose car model B  --- " << std::endl;   
}

void printCar(const Car & car, char id) {
    std::cout << "Car model " << id << " is " << car.model << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Car Brand " << id << " is " << car.brand << std::endl;
    // these probably want to say price and age, not model again
    std::cout << "Car model " << id << " is " << car.price << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Car model " << id << " is " << car.age << std::endl;
}

std::map<char, Car> cars = { 
    { 'A', { "Sedan", "Ford", 25500, 5 } },
    { 'B', { "Hatchback", "Toyota", 15500, 2 } },
};

int main() {
    printMenu();
    char option;
    std::cout << "Please Enter an option " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> option;
    if (auto it = cars.find(option); it != cars.end()) {
        printCar(it->second, it->first);
    } else {
        std::cout << "You did not choose a option :" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9oqKK384b